# YARN REST API diagnostics field

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

The YARN Resource Manager REST APIs allow for getting details for the applications submitted. Through GET **http:///ws/v1/cluster/apps** one of the fields returned is "*diagnostics*". The description for it says - "Detailed diagnostic information".

However, I always see it being empty. Can this field be used to know the exact reason why an application may have exited? Like, did it get pre-empted by the RM or it failed on its own (crashed) or got killed by RM because it started exceeding its allowed quota, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn more, I've watched this field for various apps that I submitted on YARN - Hbase, SOLR, spark, etc. and in some cases this field is used to indicate final exit message for the process. So, this field is not necessarily always empty as I wrongly noted above.